# How to generate assembly listings in Code::Blocks?

Tags: c, gcc, codeblocks

Can we generate an assembly file in code-blocks for C programs, the same way we can generate listing file when we write C-code for micro-controller?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I presume you want your Code::Blocks build to generate an annotated
assembly listing for each `.c` source file compiled.

Yes, you can do this as follows (as of Code::Blocks 12.11):

- In the Code::Blocks IDE, navigate *Settings* -> *Compiler*
- Ensure that the **Selected compiler** is GCC.
- In the tab list that begins **Compiler settings**, **Linker settings**..., 
  navigate to the last tab, **Other settings**.
- In the **Other settings** pane, select **Advanced options**, at the bottom right.
- In the **Advanced compiler options** windows, ensure that the drop-down menu
  entitled **Command** is set at **Compile single file to object file**
- See the edit box entitled **Command line macro** and confirm that it
  contains the line:

  $compiler $options $includes -c $file -o $object
- To this line append a space followed by exactly this:

  -Wa,-alhds=$objects_output_dir$file_name.list
- (Do not allow yourself to be misled at this point by the listing of
  **Command macros** at the left of the window. If it lists `$objectsoutputdir`
  instead of `$objects_output_dir` and `$filename` instead of `$file_name`, it
  is wrong.)
- Click `OK` in the **Advanced compiler options** window and then in the
  **Compiler settings** window.
- Rebuild your project.

The effect of the change you have made to the global compiler settings
is that the options:

```
-alhds=$objects_output_dir$file_name.list
```

will be passed to the assembly phase when compiling each source file `filename.c`, 
with `$objects_output_dir`replaced by the object output files directory of your project
and `$file_name` replaced by `filename`, causing the assembler to generate an 
annotated listing file `filename.list` in the same directory where `filename.o` is placed.

Unfortunately I do not see how to do this just for a selected project; so after
the change the compiler will generate the `.list` files for all projects.

If this is a nuisance, you can work around it by first configuring a "new compiler"
in Code::Blocks that is a copy of GCC, with whatever name you like, and then applying
the change I have described to this copy. To do this:

- Navigate *Settings* -> *Compiler*;
- Ensure the **Selected compiler** is GCC
- Select **Copy** and enter the name of your choice when prompted, e.g.
  "gcc-list"